# What is the Best Way to Start Closed Galera Clusters?

Tags: 18.04, mariadb, cluster, high-availability

I have a 3-Cluster Galera replication and last day electricity has gone off. When I started the Mariadb servers, I saw that cluster could not start, three of them failed. I edited the grastate.dat and executed the command "galera_new_cluster", but I think there should be a better way to make this. What is the best way to start closed Galera Clusters? Or where can I find a good tutorial for monitoring and adminning for Mariadb Galera Clusters except the official mariadb site?

I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: @David I edited